# Cosmo Db sql Azure- Reading unique documents in parallel

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We are having services which interact with cosmos DB documents. Each service is having multiple instances so that can fetch the documents in parallel.

Our requirement is to ensure that every instance should fetch/process only unique documents.. For e.g. i have master service `"S"` having instances `s1,s2,s3,s4` and having documents `d1,d2,d3,d4.........d20`. We need `s1` to fetch first batch only ( `D1,d2,d3,d4,d5`) and other instances should not fetch same documents. Each of instance should have unique documents batch. The output should be like below

s1- Process d1,d2,d3,d4,d5

s2- d6,d7,d8,d9,10

s3 - d11,d12,d13,d14,d15

s4 - d16,17,18,19,20.

What I am looking for is :

- Any read and lock document mechanism in cosmo DB -If yes, I can use them to lock documents for n seconds so that another service instance should not pick them. Any inbuilt flag.
- If we do not have any inbuilt mechanism, then I can use tags or stored procedure to replace docs and add a new property which reflects their states(Lock). But I am not sure about a scenario where two service instance will try to write /replace at the same time and both will be able to lock it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.Any read and lock document mechanism in cosmo DB -If yes, I can use them to lock documents for n seconds so that another service instance
>   should not pick them. Any inbuilt flag.

As I know, no such lock mechanism in cosmos db so that we could prevent them to be picked by service.

> 2.If we do not have any inbuilt mechanism, then I can use tags or stored procedure to replace docs and add a new property which reflects
>   their states(Lock). But I am not sure about a scenario where two
>   service instance will try to write /replace at the same time and both
>   will be able to lock it.

I suggest you adding partition key ,such as batchId. Cosmos DB to guarantee ACID for all operations that are part of a single stored procedure.

> In Cosmos DB, JavaScript is hosted in the same memory space as the database. Hence, requests made within stored procedures and triggers execute in the same scope of a database session. This enables Cosmos DB to guarantee ACID for all operations that are part of a single stored procedure/trigger.

You could find the description above from **Database program transactions** in this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming).

In addition, the `consistency level` of stored procedure or triggers is determined by the `consistency level` of the cosmos DB account you set , as stated in the official document.

Cosmos DB offers [five consistency levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels).

I'm not sure you set which consistency level, probably just default `Session` consistency level.

`Session` consistency level only ensure strong consistency in Session life cycle.
So, stored procedures you tested are not running concurrently. There will be some overlap. The subsequent updates will cover the previous updates.

Solutions:

1. You could try to change your consistency level to `Strong`. It ensures the strongest consistency, but increases the delay.
2. Or you could add `transaction locks` to your business layout to ensure strong consistency.

Hope it helps you.